# ABI Stability: Is it related with OS or Hardware?

Tags: swift, swift5

ABI Stability: This came with swift 5. Is it related to OS or hardware? Will it work with only new devices or will work with old devices with new OS?

Comment: ABI stands for Application Binary Interface. [This link has a very good detail about ABI.](https://iosdose.com/25-ios-swift-interview-questions-with-answers/#What_is_ABI_compatibility_in_Swift_5)

Answer (score 2):

ABI Stability is completely the software part of it and not the hardware .

When a language is ABI-stable, that means it can be packaged and linked directly into the operating system itself. Prior to Swift 5.0, if you build a Swift application, a Swift dynamic library is going to be embedded to that bundle, in order to support your specific Swift version

ABI stability enables OS vendors to embed a Swift Standard Library and runtime in the OS that is compatible with applications built with Swift 5 or later.

As per Apple Documentations for [Swift 5 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2)

> Swift apps no longer include dynamically linked libraries for the
>   Swift standard library and Swift SDK overlays in build variants for
>   devices running iOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2, and tvOS 12.2.

You can also check this out [Swift 5.0 - 9to5Mac](https://9to5mac.com/2019/01/28/apple-swift-5-update-ios-12-2/)

Answer (score 1):

ABI stands for **Application Binary Interface**

ABI stability enables OS vendors to embed a Swift Standard Library and runtime in the OS that is compatible with applications built with Swift 5 or later.

ABI Stability is related to "App Thinning" According to apple ***Swift apps no longer include dynamically linked libraries for the Swift standard library***.

Earlier, Swift was not ABI stable, so each binary was bundling its own version of the Swift Dynamic Library. If you open an .ipa you can find swift standard libraries (.dylib) in SwiftSupport or Frameworks, this makes the size of the .ipa large but now its small comparatively and earlier iphone models can have more apps now.